# Selenium Getxpathcount returns 0

Tags: xpath, selenium

`Selenium.GetXpathCount("xpath=/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table")` returns 0.

I used Firepath to find `/html/body/form/div[2]/div[3]/div[3]/table`, and it showed me 20 matching nodes.

Am I syntatically correct in getting the xpath count above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `xpath=` from the start of your expression.

See the documentation here, which indicates that no such prefix is necessary:

- http://www.seleniumwiki.com/tag/getxpathcount/

Comment: Thanks. I also figured out that I had to add a WaitForPageToLoad for the table to load completely before getting the count of xpath. Thanks for your advice!

Comment: @lwburk: Not to be picky, but your link merely gives an example that does not use the "xpath=" prefix; it does _not_ indicate the prefix is unnecessary in general:-). I am sure you know the following (from reading your responses to many questions) so this is for the general audience: Almost all cases where an XPath expression may be given as an argument, the receiving parameter is actually looking for a **locator** expression (XPath, CSS, DOM, or Selenium-specific) which may or may not use prefixes. GetXPathCount, on the other hand, takes an XPath argument; hence the prefix must not be used.